# Compile java using script vs eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Are there any differences when compiling a java class using a shell script and using eclipse?

I wrote a shell script which compiles a Java class. The .class file is called from a C++ JNI class. However the FindClass function returns NULL, meaning that the class could not be found.

I compiled the same source code using eclipse and replaced the .class file. Surprisingly, the FindClass function was able to find the class.

Could someone give me an explanation for this?

Comment: Eclipse has its own compiler, so the class files it generates may not be byte-for-byte identical to javac. However they should be functionally equivalent.

Comment: @pburka, I've actually had a couple people tell me that they've seen Eclipse output incorrect bytecode. That said, yes, in theory, the outputs **should** be functionally equivalent...

Comment: @KyleStrand I've had people people tell me they've seen UFOs. Without evidence I'm reluctant to believe them. FWIW, I've personally seen javac output incorrect code (it set the ACC_STRICT bit in abstract methods, which is forbidden by the spec).

Answer (score 0):

I guessing that the script fails to set CLASSPATH or **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** correctly, but Eclipse does.  Second one is more likely because you mentioned JNI.

Comment: Is there any way to check this?